# What problems in 3D-reconstruction that by adding a third camera can be solved?

Tags: computer-vision, stereo-3d, 3d-reconstruction

3D reconstruction is typically done with 2 cameras. What are the benefits of adding a 3rd camera?

Comment: No. 3d reconstruction is actually rarely only done with two cameras in real-world systems. The main benefit that comes to mind is increased coherence and therefore robustness. Thinks of it as reducing covariances (*i.e.* uncertainties). The more you get observations, the more you converge towards a stable solution.

Comment: For example, with only two cameras, you might get visual constraints that do not allow correct depth estimation (*e.g.* small baseline). In that case the covariance in the direction of the depth vector will be very large. Acquiring more data from more cameras means that you will be able to triangulate, in effect reducing the covariance along that axis.

Answer (score 1):

In bullet form:

- Less occlusions: points visible in camera A that are occluded in B may be visible in C.
- Increased accuracy - averaging more measurements of valid matches reduces error.
- Dually, increased likelihood of detecting false matches.